# How to debug child Node.JS process in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, debugging, child-process, visual-studio-code

How to debug child Node.JS process in VS Code?
Here is the example of the code that I'm trying to debug:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var scriptPath = './child-script.js';
var runner_ = spawn('node', [scriptPath]);
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no option for the debugger to attach to a certain process in VS Code. However, you could install VS Community 2015 instead. It lets you attach the debugger to a certain process, including node.js

Comment: There is a way to attach. See @Benjamin response below.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too. But it only allows you to attach to the main js, not the child process

Comment: Tried to make it stop on the first line but looks like VS Code can't connect to it.
    `var runner = spawn('node', ['--debug-brk=5858', scriptPath]);`

Comment: That's why. So far I think it's not possible right now

Comment: Actually I made it work. You need to have a breakpoint on the second line of you _child-schipt.js_  Start main process outsite VS Code. It should stop    and wait for the child to finish. Now you can **attach** from VS Code and it should stop at your breakpoint. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Whoa, a clever workaround. I'll definitely try that one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily add a new launch configuration to launch.json that allows you to attach to a running node instance with a specific port:

```
{
        "name": "Attach to Node",
        "type": "node",
        "address": "localhost",
        "port": 5870,
}
```

Just make sure you fork/spawn your node process with the *--debug* or *--debug-brk* argument.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I'm starting the debug session from VS Code for the parent process. I'd like to to attach magically to the child process.

Comment: I understood you, just make sure to spawn your node process with "--debug" and attach to the standard debug port (5858).

Comment: This doesn't work. Once I'm in debug session for the main process VS Code doesn't allow me to launch another debugger for the child.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Debugging more than one session is currently not supported. To debug the spawned process, I suggest to run the node program outside VS Code and then attach to the spawned process from within VS Code.

Comment: I've just tried with `var runner = spawn('node', ['--debug-brk', scriptPath]);`
No luck.
Looks like debugger attaches but debugging context is not available.

Comment: Here is what I have in _child-script.js_

`console.log('Hello from child');`
`console.log('Hello from child2');`
`console.log('Hello from child3');`

First of all debugger skips first line. So you need to have breakpoints after the first line in order to debug.  It's not going to stop even if **--debug-brk** was provided. I'm running Win7

Comment: If you create different launch configs for parent and child (with different names and debug ports), VS Code supports concurrent debug sessions. You can even group them together as a "composed" launch config and start them all with "F5".

Answer (score 34):

In your launch configuration add `"autoAttachChildProcesses": true` like shown below

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js"
}
```

Comment: Upvoting as this is the best solution since this option was added to VSCode in early 2018

Comment: This works with cluster not direct implementation of child-process

Comment: @GourabPaul did you find a way to make this work with a direct child process? I'm trying to do this right now and I'm still having trouble with it. I have a forked child process that does not get attached to.

Answer (score 3):

Make this change in your launch.json, **"autoAttachChildProcesses": true**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look for this npm module [child-process-debug](https://github.com/fastest963/child-process-debug).

I created 2 separate launch configurations in vscode:

One for master process, other for child process

```
   {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5858,
        "address": "localhost",
        "restart": false,
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outFiles": [],
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach child",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5859,
        "address": "localhost",
        "restart": false,
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outFiles": [],
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": null
    }
```

Workflow as follows:

1. Start master node process with `--debug` command line switch 
   `$ node --debug master.js`
2. Attach to `master.js` node process using `Attach` via debug panel
3. Place break point  in the `child.js` process
4. Quickly detach from `main` process and attach to `child` process using `Attach child`

Fro debugging purposes, you may delay message sending between processes using `setTimeout`

```
// master.js
var child = child_process.fork(__dirname + './child.js')
setTimeout(function() {
    child.send('...')
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just add this to your debugger configuration file**

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach by Process ID",
  "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
}
```

**To attach a debugger to a Process Id. A list of processes will be prompted when you run this config., in which you can select process to which you want to attach debugger.**