# Debugging NodeJS child process' VSCode babel-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, child-process

I use `babel-node` for my `runtimeExecutable` in my `launch.json` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948471/how-to-debug-nodejses6-code-in-vscode-editor). The reason for doing so is because I am using ES6 imports and breakpoints in VSCode moved around due to transpilation and the source maps.

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug",
        "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "BABEL_ENV": "debug"
        }
    }]
}
```

**app.js** *(where I am forking the child processes)*

```
(async () => {
    const process1 = fork(path.join(__dirname, "children", "process", "one.js"));
    const process2 = fork(path.join(__dirname, "children", "process", "two.js"));

    process1.send("start");
    process2.send("start");
})();
```

**one.js/two.js**

```
process.on("message", async (message) => {
    console.log("message - " + message);
    await init();
});
```

The content of the files is less important but thought I would put them there anyway. I can debug the IIFE of `app.js` perfectly fine. When skipping passed the lines where I fork new process', I get this error in the console:

> error: unknown option `--inspect-brk'

I took the `autoAttachChildProcesses` rule from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615822/how-to-debug-child-node-js-process-in-visual-studio-code) but am assuming that `babel-node` has complicated things.

I have breakpoints in both **one.js** and **two.js** in the callbacks on the "message" event but they become *unverified breakpoints* when I initialise debugging.

**EDIT**

I have now changed to use NodeJS `cluster` module instead of `child_process` purely due to all the examples I have found are using `cluster` instead.

My now **launch.json** config:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug 2",
    "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
    "console": "internalConsole",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy"
    ],
    "env": {
        "BABEL_ENV": "debug"
    },
    "skipFiles": [
        "node_modules/**/*.js",
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
    ]
}
```

Project is initalises `index.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config();
console.log("::: index.js :::");

require("./src/app.js")
```

**src/app.js**

```
import express from "express";
import session from "express-session";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import morgan from "morgan";
import cors from "cors";
import chalk from "chalk";
import cluster from "cluster";

const app = express();
const log = console.log;
const numCpus = 4;
console.log("::: app.js :::");

console.log(`::: Master or Worker?: ${(cluster.isMaster) ? "Master" : "Worker"}`);
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(morgan("combined"));
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(session({
        secret: "test",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
    }));

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
        log(chalk.green("--------------------"));
        log(chalk.green(`Host:\t${process.env.HOST || "localhost"}`));
        log(chalk.green(`Port:\t${process.env.PORT || 3000}`))
        log(chalk.green("--------------------"));
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < numCpus; i++) {
        console.log("::: forking :::");
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on("online", (worker) => {
        console.log(`Worker ${worker.id} is now online after it has been forked`);
    });
    cluster.on("listening", (worker, address) => {
        console.log(`A worker is now connected to ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
    });
    cluster.on("fork", (worker) => {
        console.log(`New worker being forked: ${worker.id}`)
    });
    cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`Worker ${worker.id} died ${signal || code}`);
    });
    cluster.on("death", (worker) => {
        console.log(`Worker ${worker.id} died`)
    });
} else {
    require("./worker.js")
}

export default app;
```

**src/worker.js**

```
console.log("I'M A NEW WORKER!")
```

If, from the terminal, I run `npm run start:dev` which runs:

> NODE_ENV=development $(npm bin)/babel-node index.js

I get the output:

[image]

which seems correct to me so the setup of the cluster seems correct.

When attempting to debug this, however, I get different results and the breakpoints in the `else` condition are never hit along with "I'M A NEW WORKER!" is never logged. The command when debugging is:

> babel-node --nolazy --inspect-brk=33597 index.js

I've placed breakpoints around **src/app.js** and **index.js**. Initially, all seems okay but after the `for` loop is complete and both `cluster.fork()`s have been run, a strange thing happens. The debug goes back and hits **index.js** for the *parent* process. Before this, the child processes exist in the call stack but only for a set amount of time *(but no console logs saying they have exited)*. After this, the debug says it is still running but no breakpoint is ever hit. The breakpoints in **src/worker.js** is *unverified*. As a result, all the logs I see in the console are:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have eventually got it working and, as I suspected, it was `babel-node` causing the issue. I removed `babel-node` from being the `runtimeExecutable` in my **launch.json** and instead added `@babel/register` as a command line argument for transpilation. My final **launch.json** looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "--require", "@babel/register"],
            "env": {
                "BABEL_ENV": "debug",
                "NODE_ENV": "debug"
            },
            "skipFiles": ["node_modules/**/*.js", "<node_internals>/**/*.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Even though this was the issue, I am still unsure as to *why* it was the issue. If someone is able to find a reason as to why it was the issue then I will happily award you with the bounty...it's going to go to waster otherwise :)